# Filter once a value

Tags: list, google-sheets, filter, match, unique

In working with a formula in Google Sheets so basically I have list of repited institutions and their corresponding ID, like this:

[image]

I used this formula to extract the unique values of institutes:

```
`=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A24,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,A2:A24),),0)),"")`
```

It gives me a list of the institutions only once, then I used this formula to do a filter for the ID of that institution:

```
=TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(FILTER($B$2:$B$24,$A$2:$A$24=D2,$B$2:$B$24<>""),""))
```

But it gives me a list of multiples times appearing that ID like this:

[image]

I would like to have just a list like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this formula:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:B)
```

Comment: It works but originally the column A is in column A AND B IS IN D so I used but it didn't work some help in that case?

Comment: @Eduardomaker try:  `=UNIQUE({A2:A, D2:D})`

Comment: And to sort it? because with that formula it looses the order

Comment: @Eduardomaker wrap it into sort: `=SORT(UNIQUE({A2:A, D2:D}))` and you can then define columns for sorting and the order: `=SORT(UNIQUE({A2:A, D2:D}), 2, 1)`